# If/else statement via hash (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, if-statement, hash

I've created a hash (still relatively new with this concept) for a contact list where the keys are the names and the values are the phone numbers (both strings). The user is asked to take an action; here is one where you search a user's full name:

```
print "Search Name: "
name_search = gets.chomp

contact_book.each { |name, number| puts "The name entered corresponds to the following phone number: #{number}\n" if name.upcase == name_search.upcase }
```

I want to put an else statement that will notify the user if the input does not match up with any of the keys when looping through the hash, but was not able to figure out a way.

Comment: `contact_book.each { |name, number| name.upcase == name_search.upcase  ? puts "The name entered corresponds to the following phone number: #{number}\n"  : puts "Do else" }`

Comment: `contact_book.each { |name, number|  if name.upcase == name_search.upcase; puts "The name entered corresponds to the following phone number: #{number}\n" ; else; puts "Do else" }`

Comment: just wondering why you are upcasing each side of the `==` in the conditional?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 To make it not case sensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) and manage the array returned

```
matched_names = contact_book.select { |name, number| name.upcase == name_search.upcase }
if matched_names.any?
   puts "The name entered corresponds to the following phone number: #{matched_names.first.last}\n"
else
   puts "The name entered has no matches\"
end
```

Note that this highlights the fact that you could have more than one entry with the same name maybe.

Comment: Awesome. That worked perfectly -- thanks @Ursus.

I have an 'Add Contact' option too, where I will also try and implement this to make sure there are no repeats in names.

Comment: Even better, [`find` takes a block argument](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) which will return the first item where that block succeeds. If you don't care about the other matches, this is usually more efficient. It just finds the first and stops.

Answer (score 1):

Within a Hash you can lookup a key like this:

```ruby
# convert all keys to upcase
contact_book_lookup = {}
hash.each_with_object(contact_book_lookup){ |(k, v), tmp_h| tmp_h[k.upcase] = v }

search_key = name_search.upcase
if contact_book_lookup.has_key? search_key 
  puts "The name entered corresponds to the following phone number:   #{contact_book_lookup[search_key]}\n"
else
  puts "The name entered has no matches\" 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers look like they will work, but seem quite verbose for what you are trying to accomplish. I guess it is only style preference, but for efficiency: If I want to see if a hash has a key I would do it like this in one line.

```
phone_num = contact_book[ name_key ]
puts ( phone_num ) ? "#{name_key}'s phone number is #{phone_num}" : "#{name_key} not found"
```

I notices someone trying to re-case everything everytime.  For efficiency you would normally do this once on storing the name, not NxM times one searching for it.